# Mongodb 2dsphere index for nested array field

Tags: php, mongodb, geolocation, indexing, geospatial

I have created collection and a object is looks like this.

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 53087f483b15eaeb6c3c9869
)
[time_from] => 2014-02-22 00:00:00
[time_to] => 2014-02-22 00:10:00
[checkin] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [time_frame] => 2014-02-22 00:00:56
        [user_id] => 1
        [loc] => Array (
            [type] => Point
            [coordinates] => Array (
                [0] => 73.43
                [1] => 42.22
            )
        )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [time_frame] => 2014-02-22 00:00:56
        [user_id] => 2
        [loc] => Array (
            [type] => Point
            [coordinates] => Array (
                [0] => 73.10
                [1] => 42.97
            )
        )
    )
}
```

I need to create "2dsphere" index for 'loc' field. The checkin field has all the location coordinates stored in array format.

I tried creating index like below.

```
db.<collection>.ensureIndex( { "checkin.loc" : "2dsphere"  } );
```

and I got this below error message.

```
"err" : "Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?:{ type: \"Point\", coordinates: [ \"73.10\", \"40.73\" ] }"
```

What I am missing? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The document you provided looks good to me, I also did a simple test with a short version of your document and it works for me.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("530cb07c009d8c323b477957"),
        "time_from" : ISODate("2014-02-25T15:02:20.714Z"),
        "checkin" : [
                {
                        "user_id" : 1,
                        "loc" : {
                                "type" : "Point",
                                "coordinates" : [
                                        73.43,
                                        42.22
                                ]
                        }
                }
        ]

db.testGeo.ensureIndex( { "checkin.loc" : "2dsphere"  } );
```

So I suggest checking other documents in the collection, some of them might be malformed for the index. Also make sure that your coordinates array elements are not strings. Because this document is not valid for 2dsphere index:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("530cb07c009d8c323b477957"),
            "time_from" : ISODate("2014-02-25T15:02:20.714Z"),
            "checkin" : [
                    {
                            "user_id" : 1,
                            "loc" : {
                                    "type" : "Point",
                                    "coordinates" : [
                                            "73.43",
                                            "42.22"
                                    ]
                            }
                    }
            ]
```

Please note the quotation marks for the coordinates elements which makes them to be strings.

**ANSWER TO THE COMMENT:**
Mongo allows only one geospatial index per collection. So you don't have to specify the whole field path for your runCommand. Collection name is enough. This should work for you if the collection name is `checkin_20140222`

```
db.runCommand( { geoNear: 'checkin_20140222', near: {type: "Point", coordinates: [73.43, 42.22]}, spherical: true, maxDistance: 40000})
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @MaksymStrukov ! . That really helped me. Also in single object I am updating user's checkin(s) in particular time interval. I need to retrieve users who are all near to the location coordinates in **checkin** array. for eg. `db.runCommand( { geoNear: 'checkin_20140222.checkin.loc', near: {type: "Point", coordinates: [73.43, 42.22]}, spherical: true, maxDistance: 40000})` but I am getting error message `[errmsg] => can't find ns` Please help me on this.

Comment: @rajeshkumarprk See the edit to my answer. P.S. Please upvote the answer if it is helpful, or mark it as answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am storing all geo values(for all users) in same document(in **checkin** array refer my example in the question). So I have to search users nearby using `geoNear` in single object. But by using your command, the result shows all values(users) for me. Please help.

Comment: Hm, I think I got your problem but it is simply not possible wih your current design. To unwind your array (turn each array element into seperate document) one has to use aggregation but you can only have geoNear as the first stage of aggregation pipeline. So the only way is to store each array element as a seperate document. for common info you can create a parent document which can be referenced by childs.

Comment: Got it @MaksymStrukov  Thanks! I can turn each array into a document. But our need is that for  10 mins once checkin(storing geo coordinates) happens for a user, meaning the records would spike for every checkin.
My concern  is about **scalability and performance** when user count reaches **million**... would Mongo be able to scale this..
Should have a distributed database system built for handling this ?

Comment: Mongo is highly scalable db, I suggest reading up on mongo sharding on the web.