# Is it possible to create geospatial index not on document level but on property level in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, geospatial

I am currently working with a mongodb containing a collection of companies with the following structure:

```
{
    "_id": "52cdef7c4bab8bd675297d8e",
    "name": "Facebook",
    "offices": [{
        "description": "Headquarters",
        "address1": "1601 Willow Road",
        "address2": "",
        "zip_code": "94025",
        "city": "Menlo Park",
        "state_code": "CA",
        "country_code": "USA",
        "latitude": 37.41605,
        "longitude": -122.151801,
        "location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-122.151801, 37.41605]
        }
    }, {
        "description": "Europe HQ",
        "address1": "",
        "address2": "",
        "zip_code": "",
        "city": "Dublin",
        "state_code": null,
        "country_code": "IRL",
        "latitude": 53.344104,
        "longitude": -6.267494,
        "location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-6.267494, 53.344104]
        }
    }, {
        "description": "New York",
        "address1": "340 Madison Ave",
        "address2": "",
        "zip_code": "10017",
        "city": "New York",
        "state_code": "NY",
        "country_code": "USA",
        "latitude": 40.7557162,
        "longitude": -73.9792469,
        "location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-73.9792469, 40.7557162]
        }
    }]
}
```

As the example shows a company can have multiple offices.

What I would like to know is, if it is possible to create a geospatial index at offices level not at document (root) level? For example, the user of my application is currently in Dublin and searches within a distance of 50km, he/she will get "Facebook, Europe HQ" in his/her results and not just "Facebook"?

If yes, how can I achieve that, if not what could I do then?

Comment: I don't see any restrictions around creating indexes on embedded array location field. Did `db.collectionname.createIndex( { "offices.location" : "2dsphere" } )` not work for you ?

Comment: @Veeram No, I tried it but it says `SyntaxError: missing : after property id`

Comment: May be a relevant post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980755/mongodb-2dsphere-index-for-nested-array-field. You should be able to create index but you can't limit the search result to display the matching embedded doc. The results are always the whole doc when it matches. So storing them office location as its own document seems to be the way.

Comment: @Veeram it works, I have just forgotten the quotes around the property name

Comment: @Veeram I have another problem yet. Some of my longitude and latitudes are null and at index creation it says, `Point must only contain numeric elements` you know how to solve this?